# How to get event file /dev/input/event* in linux

Tags: linux, embedded

I am new to linux & working on a project which includes some gpios are connected to my calixto board based on which i am performing action which i am getting from  sys/class/gpio*/value & put in a while loop but it consumes much resources so i want to make it event based i.e how to get event from /dev/input/event* file & what are the configurations needed to be done in kernel during creating uImage thanks in advance.

Comment: You might explain why you want to go event based and what do you think it is. Not sure if your hardware (unmentioned) maps the IO to those Human Input Device events, if yes at the end of the link you find some hints: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt

Answer (score 1):

Events are created by input devices, not by GPIOs directly. (Keep in mind that other sources of events can include things like mice, keyboards, touchscreens, and joysticks.) The easiest way of creating an input device from GPIOs will be to declare a `gpio_keys` platform device, either by adding one to your device tree (if you're using one), or by editing your board configuration file (if not). Details will depend heavily on the exact platform you're working with.

There's a brief walkthrough on this web site — it's for different hardware than you're working with, but the principles will be similar: http://www.armadeus.com/wiki/index.php?title=GPIO_keys

Comment: i have made changes in my both the file i.e board-calixto-evm.c and board-da850-evm.c according to given example but i didn't understand how to create a node and from where to get the code = BTN_EXTRA for my gpios which are connected to my gpio pins that are 48,49,......55.  what i want is that when i press my gpio key 48 then its input must be visible in /dev/input/event file, from where i will read the value and do my work. i have made changes during kernel compilation also but there are no directory i.e gpio48,......gpio55  and how i will test that whether the gpio is working when pressed.

Comment: whether i have to do something with pinmux because my driver is visible by using /proc/bus/input/devices

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using Asyc Access I think the following is a good start:

https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_GPIO_signals

Comment: i have made changes in my both the file i.e board-calixto-evm.c and board-da850-evm.c according to given example but i didn't understand how to create a node and from where to get the code = BTN_EXTRA for my gpios which are connected to my gpio pins that are 48,49,......55. what i want is that when i press my gpio key 48 then its input must be visible in /dev/input/event file, from where i will read the value and do my work. i have made changes during kernel compilation also but there are no directory i.e gpio48,......gpio55 and how i will test that whether the gpio is working when pressed

Comment: whether i have to do something with pinmux because my driver is visible by using /proc/bus/input/devices

Comment: I dont see any products which specify GPIO capabilities on the homepage of http://www.calixto.co.in/products.html - can you be more specific what type of USB device you have? If the device shows up differently than the example, it could be that it requires a different approach - it is device (class) specific.